# How to animate an image (with motion blur) above a video (via bpy/python script)

Tags: scripting, image

Assuming I have a movie clip in a sequence and a smaller image loaded (as below), how can the image be animated horizontally or vertically across the video?

```
mc = bpy.data.movieclips.load( movieFilePath )
img = bpy.data.images.load( imagePath )
...
se = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor_create()
se.sequences.new_clip( "the_clip", mc, 0, 0 )
```

Comment: You're wanting to do this with python? (it doesn't require python unless you're doing this for a more complex script). Motion blur requires some cheating though...

Comment: I have some requirements that mean I can't interact with the GUI. What kind of cheating for motion blur?

Comment: Okay. Well, there are ways to cheat it in the VSE by layering video clips with different offsets, although that doesn't give the best results. The other ways is to use the 3D viewport and cycles to render out the motion blur.

Comment: Could you elaborate on using the 3D viewport? is that something scriptable?

Comment: It's scriptable, but it's all a big hack. You might have to use some workarounds for to script it properly. The other thing is that the frames won't play back in realtime (except for a preview without the motion blur), they'd have to be rendered out which can take some time. Have you looked into seeing how this would all be done without python? I find it helpful a lot of the time to just try things in Blender step by step before I script them. This makes it easy to come up with a workflow and to figure out exactly what operators I need.